# Why can I call a function before it's defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, object

So using the main() method allows one to call a function before it's defined like so:

```
enter code here
def main(): 
    useless_function() 
def useless_function():
    print(" Oh, so this is what I do!")

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Why is this a thing? Why would you want to call an object before it exists?

Comment: You wouldn't ... problem solved

Comment: This is an ill conceived example, I don't know what programming resource would promote this. Python does not allow the use of objects or functions that have not been defined.

Comment: Um, is your indentation correct? Because this would give you an error.

Comment: Ok, your changed indentation is completely different.

Comment: This isn't calling a function before it's defined. `main` is defined. `useless_function` is defined. `main` is called. `useless_function` is called, in that order.

Comment: Essentially, because `main` and `useless_function` are both added to the global scope from top to bottom as Python parses the file. At the end, the `main` function is called during which Python actually steps into the functions and executes the inner function call, at which point everything is already defined.

Comment: Thanks guys that clears it up for me!

Comment: When you run python code it will define functions before actually running it meaning that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a function in Python, no evaluation or checking of the body is done (other than parsing). When you call the function , it executes. It looks for "useless_function" in the local scope of the function. If it doesn't find it, Python looks for it in the next higher scope (in this case global). If it exhausts these possibilities with no success, a `NameError` exception is thrown.

```
def f1():
    return f2()

try:
    f1()
except NameError:
    print('Name error!')

def f2():
    print('Hello')

f1()

def f2():
    print('Hello World')

f1()
```

The output of the above program is:

```
Name error!
Hello
Hello World
```

Without this behavior, try to think how you would create a pair of recursive functions (f1 calls f2 which calls f1 ...).

The key to clearing up your misunderstanding is realizing the instruction `useless_function()` is actually two instructions:

1. Get the object of name `useless_function`
2. Call the object's method named `__call__`

Since the first step is not executed at the creation of the function but instead at every function call, you see the behavior asked about in your question

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking why this works - Python parses everything top to bottom, but until you call your function no inner-function code is executed.

Since you have your `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` call after the `useless_function()` is defined, call to the `main()`, which calls `useless_function()`, is not invalid because `useless_function()` exists at that point.

If you're asking why is this allowed - think of this in an OOP setting. Classes are also read top-bottom but if you would not allow methods to call one another regardless of their position there wouldn't be much of OOP to speak about. As long as the whole parent/enclosing structure is parsed before the actual execution - the internal order doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You should probably upvote if an answer is helpful to you. Don't forget to mark your favorite answer (and most relevant to you) as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

When Python encounters the `useless_function()` line of code in `main`, it basically generates these instructions:

- fetch the object referened by that name
- call it (i.e. invoke its `__call__` method)

As you can see, `useless_function` does not have to be defined at that point. It must exist when `main` is called.

Try this to see that we can give the name to a different object:

```
def another_function():
    print("What?!")
```

and then:

```
main()
useless_function = another_function
main()
```